Postfix: send an email with the postmaster account (postmaster@example.com)
I have set up a Postfix server on my Ubuntu 24.04 server. It is also running well, but the domain used has suddenly ended up on a domain blacklist from Spamhaus. To request the removal of the application, you have to send a mail as postmaster@example.com. How can I interactively send a mail as user postmaster? I use virtual mailboxes and have set an alias from user@example.com to postmaster@example.com. Is it possible to send mails as postmaster?


I found a solution. In Thunderbird I could enter a second identity postmaster@example.com and send the email that I needed to send.
